# How to convert a text file with one column into multiple columns?

Tags: python

I have a text file with repeating inputs all stacked in a column, with two spaces separating the next group of data :

```
ID    1
Na   2
SK   3

ID    2
Na   4
SK   3

ID    3
Na   6
SK   6
```

I want to create separate columns for each data set like this:

```
ID    1         ID    2        ID    3
Na   2         NA   4       NA   6
SK   3         SK   3       SK   6
```

I have tried several options but I am getting a nested which I cannot seem to manipulate. Thanks your help in advance.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you want your output to look like. Do you really just want a single line with everything on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script will iterate through each line of the data file, split it into a list, then push each entry into a dict, using the 1st part as the key and the 2nd as the value), then print out the resulting dictionary in roughly the format you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open('data.txt') as data_f:
    for line in data_f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            key, val = line.split()
            data_dict[key].append(val)

for item, vals in data_dict.items():
    print(["{} {}".format(item, val) for val in vals])
```